# Marketing Cloud SMS Push to users in market

Tags: marketing-cloud, geolocation, sms

We have some geofencing set up to push a message to users when they cross a boundary. We have a hurricane coming and we want to notify users who are in the city right now. Does anyone know of a way to send an on-demand message to people inside of a location boundary? I'd image the system can track if you have entered, but not exited the boundary right? That would mean we should be able to pull a list of all people who are currently here. At least that seems logical to me... Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new message for a geofence area it will be displayed on the device as soon as it is downloaded if the end user is already within the defined boundary.  The message will be downloaded if:

1. The application is brought into the foreground
2. The daily geolocation message refresh occurs (randomly in a 24 hour window)

Geofence Messages are already targeted at a specific fence definition so there's no need to target a specific list of people.  Also, the Marketing Cloud does not store the location of a device.  Geocoordinates are used when making the REST call to get a list of fences and nothing more.